# Find key in Array and display the value

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a little problem with array. Im using codeigniter. What i want to do, is something like that:

```
$studentSchool = $students->schoolId;
echo $shools->id[$studentSchool]->schoolName;
```

Its in foreach $students loop, and array with schools looks like that:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [schoolName] => Akademia Ekonomiczna ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [schoolName] => Politechnika ) )
```

Those are my first steps in php and codeigniter, so please have mercy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$schools` is the array, you have to access the it as an array. It won't have an `id` property;

You should build your `$schools` array such that the index of element corresponds to the ID of the school. I.e. you should have:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [schoolName] => ... ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [schoolName] => ... ) 
)
```

Then you can do:

```
echo $schools[$studentSchool]->schoolName;
```

---

Or, if the schools are sorted by ID and the IDs are continuous, you can also do:

```
 echo $schools[$studentSchool - 1]->schoolName;
```

---

Otherwise you have to loop over the array to find the right entry for the given ID which is expensive and unnecessary.

[Learn more about arrays.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: But in $studentSchool consist school Id, and in array there are two objects, and now $studentSchool points to the object, not to 'id' key. Am i right? When i try set $studentSchool to 2, and i have school with id 2, i get "Trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
foreach ($students as $student):

    // Prints the School name for this student
    echo $student->schoolName;

endforeach;
```

Or maybe this?:

```
// Prints the School name for the first student
echo $students[0]->schoolName
```

EDIT: This is what you want?

```
$studentSchool = $students->schoolId;
echo $shools[$studentSchool]->schoolName;
```

Comment: No, no ;) I have schools in different table in sql, and in users table there is 'schoolId' and i want to take that id and find it in schools array and display its name(the school name) :)

Comment: Aha OK, you said it was your first day with php so I wasn't sure how obvious this would be :)